# Looking for IOT sensor data for the task of classification

Tags: sensors

Is there any dataset of IOT sensors labelled for the task of classification ?

Comment: IoT sensors are just regular sensors coupled with some means of transferring/receiving this data... so why not just use regular ole sensor data and just pretend that it was sent to the cloud?

Comment: @BrandonLoudermilk do you have an example of such "ole sensor data ?"

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look here for various sensor data: http://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/great-sensor-datasets-to-prepare-your-next-career-move-in-iot-int

Comment: These datasets are not labelled or are not suited for the task of classification